# WiFiDirect on Windows how to find devices connected to my host

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct

On a Windows machine I have a process which acts as WiFiDirect Advertisement Publisher.
On the same machine I have a service and in this service I need to get a list of the peers connected: I need the IP and if possible the MAC of each connected device.

Using the WiFiDirectConnectionListener class, I get the device which have been connected and disconnected but I need a way to get all the devices already connected when the service starts.

The following code does not finds the devices whic are connected:

```
 serviceSelector = WiFiDirectDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
 DeviceInformationCollection deviceInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(serviceSelector);
```

How can I do it?